# Sign In User or Admin

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Please help me with the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: iman@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString
at com.example.quizapp.SignInActivity$3.onDataChange(SignInActivity.java:85)
```

My code:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText memail;
    private EditText mpassword;
    private Button mlogin;
    private Button mregister;
    private ProgressBar mpgbar;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference users;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = database.getReference("User");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        memail = findViewById(R.id.emailtv);
        mpassword = findViewById(R.id.passwordtv);
        mlogin = findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
        mregister = findViewById(R.id.regBtn);
        mpgbar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        mregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return;
            }
        });

        mlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               LoginUser(memail.getText().toString(),mpassword.getText().toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private void LoginUser(final String email, final String pwd) {

        if(isEmpty()) return;
        inProgress(true);
        users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(email).exists())
                {
                    if(!email.isEmpty())
                    {
                        User login = dataSnapshot.child(email).getValue(User.class);
                        if(login.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Admin"))
                        {
                            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pwd)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, AdminPage.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish(); return;
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else if(login.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("User"))
                        {
                            if(isEmpty()) return;
                            inProgress(true);
                            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(memail.getText().toString(),mpassword.getText().toString())
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                                            Toast.makeText(SignInActivity.this, "User signed in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                            Intent intent = new Intent(SignInActivity.this, Home.class);
                                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                            finish(); return;
                                        }
                                    });
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void inProgress(boolean x) {
        if (x) {
            mpgbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mlogin.setEnabled(false);
            mregister.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            mpgbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mlogin.setEnabled(true);
            mregister.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmpty() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(memail.getText().toString())) {
            memail.setError("REQUIRED");
            return true;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mpassword.getText().toString())) {
            mpassword.setError("REQUIRED");
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


}
```

Java line 85 is `if(dataSnapshot.child(email).exists())`

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use something as a intermediate node that has special symbols like '.'(dot)

From [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#how_data_is_structured_its_a_json_tree)

> If you create your own keys, they must be UTF-8 encoded, can be a maximum of 768 bytes, and cannot contain ., $, #, [, ], /, or ASCII control characters 0-31 or 127. You cannot use ASCII control characters in the values themselves, either.

You can simply use some unique id of user as key or if you really want to use email as key, replace all '.' with '_' underscore or something similar;

Comment: Thanks :) I'll make adjustments

Comment: @NurImanMardhiahBtAbdulHam accept the answer please if it solves the problem

Comment: Hi but then this come out  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.quizapp.Model.User.getType()' on a null object reference on line   if (login.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Admin"))

Comment: please ask another question on the problem you are facing instead asking in the comments.

Comment: Hi I post another question